# adding totals on grid not working via jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, updatepanel

Not sure what i am doing wrong here but I have a webpage which has a usercontrol wrapped in an update panel. This usercontrol has a gridview with a textbox in an ItemTemplate and a textbox in a footer template. The textbox in the footertemplate is supposed to get the calculated value from a function in jquery. Below is my script to get the total but the total doesn't get calculated. Please advise what am I doing wrong here. Also, let me know if I need to provide additional information. This script is in the master page. I tested to make sure jquery is working by putting the alert after the document ready which it works. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<script language="javascript">
    var totalQuantity = 0;
    $(document).ready(function() {
    //alert('This is test');
    $(document).on('blur', 'input[id^="MainContent_MainContent_ucProjectionSet3_upProjections"]', function() {
            alert('This is test');
            totalQuantity = 0;
            $('input[id^="MainContent_MainContent_ucProjectionSet3_gvProjections_txtCurrentTime_"]').each(function(index) {
                doTotalCal($(this).attr("id"));
            });
        });
        function doTotalCalc(_id) {
            var indexVal = _id.Replace("MainContent_MainContent_ucProjectionSet3_gvProjections_txtCurrentTime_", "");
            console.log(indexVal);
            var strTotalQuantity = $('input[id^="MainContent_MainContent_ucProjectionSet3_gvProjections_txtCurrentTime_' + indexVal + '"]').val().replace("$", "");
            totalQuantity += Number(strTotalQuantity);
        }
        $("#MainContent_MainContent_ucProjectionSet3_gvProjections_lblCurrentTimeTotal").html(totalQuantity);
    }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this without using update panel. I didn't need to have an asynchronous postback for this project, so removing it was a fine option in making the jquery to work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("[id*=gvProjections]input[type=text][id*=txtCurrentTime]").keyup(function(e) {
            GrossTotal();
        });
    });
    var gross;
    function GrossTotal() {
        gross = 0;
        $("[id*=gvProjections]input[type=text][id*=txtCurrentTime]").each(function(index, item) {

            gross = gross + Number($(item).val());
        });

        $("[id*=gvProjections][id*=lblCurrentTimeTotal]").text(gross);
    }
    function isNumberDecimalKey(evt) {
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
        if (charCode == 46) //decimal
            return true
        else if (charCode > 57 || (charCode > 31 && charCode < 48))
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
```